# returning value in simple recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I want to generate a random integer. In order to check that its not already generated, I want to add it to the array, and next time when generating the new integer, I want to check if it exists in the array, if it exists then generate again (until it generates some integer which doesn't exist) and then return the integer.

I'm trying it with the following recursion function, but the recursion doesn't work correctly (when it generates the number that exists, then there is problem).

```js
var ids = [];

function generateID() {

  var newID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;  //small range for test
   
  if( jQuery.inArray(newID, ids) == -1 ) {
        
      ids.push(newID);     
      
      return newID;  //is it correct to return from here?
      
  } else {
    //problem part
    console.log(newID + " exists");
    generateID();    
  }  

}

function getID() {

    var i = generateID();
    console.log(i);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="getID();" >Generate ID</button>
```

Comment: For it to be recursive, you need to `return generateID();`, inside `generateID`. But if you click the button 7 times, you'll get an infinite recursive loop and your page will be completely unresponsive. Make sure the user can't click it more than 6 times _(or any higher number that you'll use in your real world project - it might be a rare edge-case, but it's a good habit to take care of these)_

Comment: in the else block where you have the problem. try `return generateID()` insteads of just having `generateID()`

Comment: a secure app would not populate clientside all the taken ids, this is a job for serverside if its needed at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return the output of `generateId` in the else case as well. Also you can just use `Array.includes` method to find out if something exists in an array.

```js
var ids = [];

function generateID() {

  var newID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; //small range for test

  if (!ids.includes(newID)) {
    ids.push(newID);
    return newID;
  } else {
    console.log(newID + " exists");
    return generateID();
  }
}

function getID() {
  var i = generateID();
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getID();">Generate ID</button>
```

Hope this helps !